# No data found in my database using $wpdb

Tags: wordpress

i have a problem regarding inserting data in the database using $wpdb

i can browse the fields but theres no text inside it, only blank. i know that the form works because i can browse my fields but no data inside the fields.

```
   <div class="wrap">
    <h1>Hello WordPress!</h1>
    <form class="form" method="POST" action="">

                Last Name: &nbsp &nbsp <input type="text" name="lastname" required="required">
                First Name:<input width="50" type="text" name="firstname" required="required">  
                Middle Name: <input width="50" type="text" name="middlename" required="required">
                Nickname:&nbsp <input width="50" type="text" name="nickname" required="required">

                Last Name:&nbsp &nbsp <input type="text" name="" style="width: 300px;"><br>
                <button id="save" name="save" type="submit">Save</button>
                </form> 
   </div>

   <?php

   global $wpdb;
   $wpdb->insert("wp_employee",array(
    "lastname"=>$lastname,
   "firstname" =>$firstname ));

    ?>
```

i dont know wheres the problem or the missing code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$wpdb->insert( 
'table', 
array( 
    'column1' => 'value', 
    'column2' => 'value'
), 
array( 
    '%s', 
    '%d' 
) 
);

<?php $wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format ); ?>
```